# No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container

Tags: c#, ninject, aop

Consider this code:

```
public class IocConfig
{
    protected static StandardKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    public static void RegisterIoc(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
        {
            RegisterDependency();
            config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        }

    }

    public static void RegisterIoc()
    {

        RegisterDependency();
    }

    private static void RegisterDependency()
    {
        if (Kernel == null)
        {
            Kernel = new StandardKernel();
        }
        Kernel.Bind<CallCenterLogger>().ToSelf().Intercept().With(new TimingInterceptor());
    }

    public static T GetType<T>()
    {
        RegisterDependency();
        return Kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

in this line:

```
        Kernel.Bind<CallCenterLogger>().ToSelf().Intercept().With(new TimingInterceptor());
```

I get this error:

Error loading Ninject component IAdviceFactory

No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Suggestions:

1) If you have created a custom subclass for KernelBase, ensure that you have properly

```
 implemented the AddComponents() method.
```

2) Ensure that you have not removed the component from the container via a call to RemoveAll().

3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.

How can solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have added *Ninject.Extensions.Interception* but not any of the concrete implementations *Ninject.Extensions.Interception,DynamicProxy* or *Ninject.Extensions.Interception,LinFu*